# Can't get code into .txt

Tags: batch-file

**I'm making a batch file that will create another .bat, and it's not working. Here's my code (I know the game works, but I can't get it to put the working game in a .txt)**

```
:new2
echo(
:game
cls
@echo off
echo Welcome to Tobey's Rock Paper Scissors game!
pause
:start
cls
echo Please select a method of destruction
echo [1] Rock
echo [2] Scissors
echo [3] Paper
set /p choice=
if %%choice%% EQU 1 goto rock
if %%choice%% EQU 2 goto scissors
if %%choice%% EQU 3 goto paper
goto goof
:rock
Set /A enemy=%random% %% 3
if %%enemy%% EQU 0 goto tie
if %%enemy%% EQU 1 goto win
if %%enemy%% EQU 2 goto loss
:tie
echo Your opponent threw rock, it's a tie!
pause
goto start
:win
echo Your opponent threw scissors, you win!
pause
goto start
:loss
echo Your opponent threw paper, you lose!
pause
goto start
:scissors
Set /A enemy=%random% %% 3
if %%enemy%% EQU 0 goto loss1
if %%enemy%% EQU 1 goto tie1
if %%enemy%% EQU 2 goto win1
:tie1
echo Your opponent threw rock, you lose!
pause
goto start
:win1
echo Your opponent threw scissors, it's a tie!
pause
goto start
:loss1
echo Your opponent threw paper, you win!
pause
goto start
:paper
Set /A enemy=%%random%% %% 3
if %%enemy%% EQU 0 goto win1
if %%enemy%% EQU 1 goto loss1
if %%enemy%% EQU 2 goto tie1
:tie1
echo Your opponent threw rock, you win!
pause
goto start
:win1
echo Your opponent threw scissors, you lose!
pause
goto start
:loss1
echo Your opponent threw paper, it's a tie!
pause
goto start
:goof
cls
echo You dun goofed.
pause
goto game
)>>%fileinfo%.bat
TYPE %fileinfo%.bat
```

**It's not creating a new file, any advice? Note: This isn't the full code, I have code to goto :new2 and code that defines %fileinfo%.**

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly One hundred percent clear on this, But I believe you want to copy your whole code into a text file right?
So at the ending you have

```
goto game
)>>%fileinfo%.bat
TYPE %fileinfo%.bat
```

So what your doing here is Copying

```
ECHO(
::CODE into the file
)>>
```

Code into your file Now I would actually do this

```
goto game
)>>%fileinfo%.txt
TYPE %fileinfo%.txt > %fileinfo%.bat ::Or the other way around...
```

I'm pretty sure that would work but I'm not exactly sure at the case your doing with your TYPE command as far as I'm sure this should work

Comment: the problem is: `echo(` works not as intended. It only echoes a blank line, then the next line is executed. Also `echo (` will not work - it echoes a `(` only.

Comment: Yeah Stephan is right, I get a blank file and then the code executes in the same window. Any suggestions then?

Answer (score 0):

for each line of code you want to include into another batch file, put `echo` in front of it and `>>example.bat` behind it.
so if you want a new file containing:

```
@echo off
echo hello world
pause
```

then just include this code in your first batch file:

```
echo @echo off>>example.bat
echo echo hello world>>example.bat
echo pause>>example.bat
```

Just replace "example.bat" with your own file name. It can be a batch file or not.

Also if you're a bit lazy and don't want to do that with hundreds of lines of code, might I suggest looking into the Notepad++ macro feature that'll add it in to your batch file (almost) completely automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If it's okay to set the "new" code to the very end of your batchfile, this will do.
You even don't have to escape special characters.
But you have to know, on which line your code starts (here it's line 10). If you add or delete code before that line, you will have to correct the number here: `more +<linenumber>`

```
@echo off
echo generating new file
more +10 %~nx0 >newfile.bat
type newfile.bat
call newfile.bat
echo It works!


exit /b
next line is the first one to copy
@echo off
rem new bat file
echo hello, it's me, %username%!
echo I'm a new file
echo generated by another file.
```